# how to load routes dynamically from database in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes, dynamic-routing

I want to load routes on every requests, i have tried to put it this code `RegisterBundles(RouteTable.Bundles)` to the `Application_Beginrequest`.

seems this method helped me but also now when i refresh the page i am getting an errors on browser.

- WebResource.axd (net::ERR_ABORTED 500)
- ScriptResource.axd (net::ERR_ABORTED 500)
- /bundles/all?v=klnl4k  (Refused to apply style from ".." because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.)

How can i load routes dynamically from database without an error?

Comment: Can you please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/archive/blogs/rickandy/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms)? Are you trying to register js,css bundles? It talks about having an App_Start folder and creating the BundleConfig class in there.

Comment: @OguzOzgul i am getting these errors because i want to load routes dynamically from database on every page load. BundleConfig still stay in App_Start without any problem

Comment: Can you share you BundleConfig.cs? I will reproduce.

Comment: @OguzOzgul i can share, problem is not disapper even if we disable/remove BundleConfig in a project. Routing causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i say i was thinking about the routing problem. Problem is when routing loads dynamically than it seems same route is loading again and it makes problem for scriptresources and bundling.

I put `routes.Clear();` before load the routes and my problem is disappeared.

I hope this information will help you to understand your problem and you can solve this error just like that.

Cheers